# Wifi not getting connected but LAN cable connection is working. Please help

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, dell

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS from Windows 10. After installation system is not detecting any Wifi it says no adapters available. But when connected through LAN cable the internet works.

I tried couple of things but nothing helped.

```
rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
lshw -c network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 05
       serial: b8:ca:3a:c3:5e:d2
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.0.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0404000-c0404fff memory:c0400000-c0403fff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:c0500000-c0507fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Please help!

Answer (score -1):

Code:

```
sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source && sudo apt install git dkms
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Reboot
If you notice weak signal try
Code:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=1
```

and see if it is better, if not do 
Code:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=2
```

Resource [Worked for me](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392454)